# Is it good to use $.getScript to get cross domain js file that contain json content?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp

I am new to `JSONP`, below is my case:

I use `PHP` to write a js file with `JSON` content for front-end to read, I tried the way below and it's works.

But, I want to ask

A) is it necessary to include a `jsoncallback()` to wrap the `JSON` content in `album.js`?

B) is it good to use `$.getScript()` to read js file contain JSON content for cross domain?

Thanks

**1. code to load js file**

```
$.getScript("http://127.0.0.1:8080/album.js")

function jsoncallback (data){
    $.each(data, function() {
        console.log($(this))
    })
}
```

**2. album.js content**

```
jsoncallback([{
        "id": "23",
        "author": "roy",
        "email": "a",
        "age": "0",
        "tel": "1",
        "title": "test",
        "image_name": "Lighthouse.jpg",
        "image_type": "image\/jpeg",
        "image_size": "561276",
        "status": "1",
        "create_date": "2013-04-03 14:39:32",
        "modify_date": "2013-04-09 19:25:07"
    }, {
        "id": "22",
        "author": "roy",
        "email": "a",
        "age": "0",
        "tel": "1",
        "title": "test",
        "image_name": "Desert.jpg",
        "image_type": "image\/jpeg",
        "image_size": "845941",
        "status": "1",
        "create_date": "2013-04-03 14:39:29",
        "modify_date": "2013-04-09 19:25:02"
    }
])
```

Comment: It is ok but it is better to pass the the name of the callback function as parameter, to keep you code reuse able. And if you use jquery I would use the included jsonp functionality, because it has a timeout option, and per request callback possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A and B: Yes. This is how JSONP works.

You can re-write it as this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/album.js",
    jsonpCallback: "jsonpcallback",
    jsonp: false,
    dataType: "jsonp"
}).done(function(data){
    console.log(data); // array of objects
});
```

Comment: It works, thanks. But do you know why your script can placed inside `$(document).ready` and run successfully, and mine script can't placed inside `$(document).ready` because it will have js error `TypeError: jsoncallback is not a function`?

Comment: @CharlesYeung because yours requires the function to be global. Mine lets jQuery create that global function for me. If you modified yours to `window.jsonpcallback = function(data){...` it would work.

Comment: You should use .success instead of .done, which according to the jquery documentation is deprecated... "As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success()." https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @jumpfightgo Just to be clear, you should use the success option, not `.success`